# Is there any way to stop activity logs on github after deployment on vercel?

Tags: github-actions, continuous-deployment, vercel

When we connect github repo to vercel all the deployment will go on Environment activity on github and I don't want these history.
what I have tried -

- I disconnected repo from vercel by doing this a problem occured where my Pull request are not getting preview URL, but I want all the preview url's on every PULL_REQUEST for deployment I am using a github action and it is working fine on PUSH or COMMIT but when a PR get raised it was unable to access github secrets. so, we have used a workflow run where we connected one workflow to another first a workflow will run on PR and after that another workflow will trigger and it will deploy on vercel but I am unable to get the preview URL on that Pull_request.
- so, what I want is either a way to stop these env activity logs or a
  way where I disconnect the repo from vercel and when a PR raised we
  get a preview urls on those PR.
- I don't want to use pull_request_target and I don't want to make
  collaborator to every user who send a Pull_request

Comment: not that it solves your problem, but what is the issue with these environments?

Comment: we get 100s of PR on our repo in a single day and each time it get deployed or cancelled one activity log get created that's why we don't want it...